# How to prevent escape key from cancelling page reload in laravel?

Tags: javascript, keyboard, stripe-payments

I have a laravel ecommerce app which uses stripe as the payment gateway.

Everything is working properly but when I submit the form, the page loads and when I use the escape key the loading stops which messes up everything. May I know how can I disable the escape key in my website?

I tried adding the following to my javascript file but nothing seems to be happening:

```
var charCode = e.charCode || e.keyCode || e.which;
if (charCode == 27) {
   return false;
}
```

Comment: how about you just not hit 'escape' which is a shortcut of the browser for 'stop'

Comment: @lagbox I know that me not hitting 'escape' is an option. But when the app goes in production mode if any customer hits 'escape' it will mess up everything for him, I don't want to risk that.

Comment: If it's a default browser behavior, then you should leave it be. It's always a bad idea trying to change the behavior people are use to.